# How to set gradient filter

Tags: flutter, list, gradient

Gradient filter to image list
(https://i.stack.imgur.com/3Agi7.jpg)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3Agi7.jpg)

I am working with flutter. Now i faced a problem in which the list of images shown in the screen have filter with gradient. I just want to make that effect in my list which can placed in the screen
How can i do it with that filter?

Answer (score 1):

if I understand what you mean
You wrap your photo inside a Container
next use property foregroundDecoration and put that gradient on your photos
like this

```
Container(
height: size.height * 0.25,
width: double.infinity,
foregroundDecoration: BoxDecoration(
  gradient: LinearGradient(
  colors: [
    Colors.blue.withOpacity(0.5),
    Colors.white
  ]
)),
decoration: BoxDecoration(
 image: DecorationImage(
 image: AssetImage("assets/images/flowers-276014_640.jpg"),
 fit: BoxFit.cover)))
```